Can we use Present Perfect Tense for actions that happened years ago, but I want the listener to focus on the result that is still relevant?
Can we use Present Perfect Tense for actions that happened years ago, but I want the listener to focus on the result that is still relevant? 
for the context, let’s say, I created a website a year ago. and someone asks me if you have ever created a website yourself.
Can I answer “ Yes, I have created a website.”
or do I need to use past simple as it is not a recent action?

This has all been said before here. It depends on what you want to say. You can simply signal the past with the present perfect or you can indicate an action that is completely over with the simple past. And this is a typical pattern: Pers 1: Yes, I have created a website. Pers 2: Oh? When did you create it? Pers 1: I designed it last week. That present prefect could just as well have been simple past... Forget relevance today: Remember whether you want to signal a specific past or just past as a general thing. That is what you have to grasp in this example.

In your example context, the other person probsably used Present Perfect to ask something like "Have you ever created a website yourself?", so it would be perfectly natural to reply "Yes, I have" (truncated from "Yes, I have created a website"). Personally I don't think it makes much difference how long ago you did something. If the fact of you having done it is of current relevance (which it probably is - someone's asking about it, so maybe they want to to do it again now), then Present Perfect is a perfectly reasonably choice (but you don't have to use it, obviously).

@FumbleFingers Yes, I have. is not truncated. It's called an answer ellipsis. And I repeat: what is likely is not what the point is. The point is *what a speaker wishes to express. Not what we imagine they want to express. Have you created a website? is as "likely" as Did you create a website?.

@Lambie: "Did you create a website?" might well be asked in the course of a conversation about the past with no direct relevance to tme of speaking. But I find it hard to imagine a context where "Have you [ever] created a website?" could be asked without the answer having current relevance. But I'm a bear of limited imagination - I can't understand why you would want to tell me that I was mistaken in saying "Yes, I have" is truncated from an "underlying" longer utterance. You're not teaching me anything I need to know, so it's a bit irritating.
